# AWS - Target Group Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I have a load balancer and an Nginx that sits behind the LB.

Below is the nginx config.

```
upstream app {
    server service_discovery_name.local:5005;
}

server {   // Reverse proxy for VPC ES to be available on public

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass vpc-es-domain-url;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {  // reverse proxy for django app

    listen 8005;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I've a listener attached to the ALB, listening at port `80`, that forwards the traffic to the target IP. The target group has the private IP of the Nginx container. I use Fargate-ECS container.

Now when I route to `ALB_url:80`, it opens up the elasticsearch. However, when I route to `ALB_url:8005`, it fails to load anything. The django_app is running at port `5005`, check by explicitly browsing to the IP=:5005.

I believe the nginx config is right. I want my traffic to be routed via `ALB -> Nginx -> apps`. What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you configure an ALB you must create a listener, specify the port and the action(forward the request to Target Group or make redirects), you can create a multiples listener using different ports, for example, you can have a listener listening in 80 port and doing redirects to HTTPs and another listener with 443 port forwarding the request to Target Group.

According to that, I understand that your configuration is:
- ALB listening in 80 port and sending the request to Target Group.
- Target Group listening in 80 port and sending the request to Fargate Task(nginx server)

When you route to ALB_URL:80 the request is forwarded to Target Group by 80 port and the request is sending to Fargate task. But when you route to ALB_URL:8005 that will no work because the ALB doesn't have a listener for that port.

You can create a listener with 8005 port that forwards the request to a Target Group listening in the 8005. with this configuration when you route ALB_url:8005 the request will be sent to TG created and then will send to the Fargate task and will take the configuration into the Nginx config.

ALB---> listener 80 ----> Target Groupt port 80  ----> ECS Task Nginx

ALB---> listener 8005 ---> Target Groupt port 8005 ----> ECS Task Nginx

Don't forget to validate the Security groups to allow 8005 port

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-group-routing-configuration

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can I've one target group listening to multiple ports? ie when I do ALB:80 or ALB:81 or ALB:PORT, it automatically gets route to NGINX with the respective port and then it should be upto nginx conf to return the response?

Comment: you can have one port by Target Group only
the request is sent to Nginx and if nginx receives the request and apply the configuration made for that port, for example, you sent a request to ALB:8005, the request is sent to TG with port 8005 and sent to the task, for example, HTTP_Request:8005, nginx verify the config and sends the response